# ChangeConflictException when updating rows with LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a form which contains a data grid and a save button.

When the user clicks the save button I check for new rows by checking a specific column. If its value is 0 I insert the row to database, and if the column value is not 0 then I update that row.

I can insert correctly but when updating an exception occurs:

> ChangeConflictException was unhandled,1 of 6 updates failed.

I have checked the update statement and I'm sure it's correct. What is the problem, can any one help me?

```
int id;
for (int i = 0; i < dgvInstructores.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    id = int.Parse(dgvInstructores.Rows[i].Cells["ID"].Value.toString());
    if (id == 0)
    {
        dataClass.procInsertInstructores(name, nationalNum, tel1, tel2, 
                                            address, email);
        dataClass.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        dataClass.procUpdateInstructores(id, name, nationalNum, tel1, tel2, 
                                            address, email);
        dataClass.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

I'm using linq to query sql server2005 database and vs2008

the stored procedure for 'procUpdateInstructores' is :

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER proc [dbo].[procUpdateInstructores]
@ID int,
@name varchar(255),
@NationalNum varchar(25),
@tel1 varchar(15),
@tel2 varchar(15),
@address varchar(255),
@email varchar(255)
as
begin

BEGIN TRANSACTION

update dbo.Instructores
set
Name = @name , NationalNum = @NationalNum ,
tel1 = @tel1 , tel2 = @tel2 , address = @address , email = @email
where ID = @ID

IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) AND (@@ERROR = 0)
     BEGIN
          COMMIT TRANSACTION
     END
ELSE
     BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
     END
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, (working with .net forms and mvc with linq-to-sql) I have found that several times if the form collection contains the ID parameter of the data object then the update surely fails.

Even if the ID is the actual ID, it is still flagged as 'propertyChanged' when you bind it or update it or assign to another variable.

As such can we see the code for your stored procs? More specifically, the update proc?

The code you have posted above is fine, the exception should be coming from your stored proc.

However if you are confident that the proc is correct then perhaps look at the HTML code being used to generate the table. Some bugs might be present with respect to 0/1 on ID columns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of further information (what your SQL or C# update code looks like...) my first recommendation would be to do SubmitChanges once, outside the for loop, rather than submitting changes once per row.

Comment: i'm sorry , i use sql server 2005 and vs2008

Comment: when i do SubmitChanges once outside the for loop i think that the problem solved but another problem happened that's its duplicate the inserted row in the database

Answer (score 0):

It appears in this case that you are using a DataGridView (thus WinForms). I further guess that your dataClass is persisted on the form so that you loaded and bound the DataGridView from the same dataClass that you are trying to save the changes to in this example.

Assuming you are databinding the DataGridView to entities returned via LINQ to SQL, when you edit the values, you are marking the entity in question that it is needing to be updated when the next SubmitChanges is called.

In your update, you are calling `dataClass.procUpdateInstructores(id, name, nationalNum, tel1, tel2, address, email);` which immediately issues the stored procedure against the database, setting the new values as they have been edited. The next line is the kicker. Since your data context still thinks the object is still dirty, SubmitChanges tries to send another update statement to your database with the original values that it fetched as part of the Where clause (to check for concurrency). Since the stored proc updated those values, the Where clause can't find a matching value and thus returns a concurrency exception.

Your best bet in this case is to modify the LINQ to SQL model to use your stored procedures for updates and inserts rather than the runtime generated versions. Then in your parsing code, simply call SubmitChanges without calling procUpdateInstructores manually. If your dbml is configured correctly, it will call the stored proc rather than the dynamic update statement.

Also, FWIW, your stored proc doesn't seem to be doing anything more than the generated SQL would. Actually, LINQ to SQL would give you more functionality since you aren't doing any concurrency checking in your stored proc anyway. If you are required to use stored procs by your DBA or some security policy, you can retain them, but you may want to consider bypassing them if this is all your stored procs are doing and rely on the runtime generated SQL for updates.